# MediatorLiveData sources don't update during testing

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a `MediatorLiveData` living in my viewmodel that is supposed to react to `LiveData` emissions from the model layer, taking actions and updating its listeners when necessary. For some reason, the sources don't update during testing.

```
class MyViewModel(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {
    private val liveData1: LiveData<String> = repository.getString1()
    private val livedata2: LiveData<String> = repository.getString2()

    val currentState = MediatorLiveData<MyState>

    init {
        currentState.addSource(liveData1) {
            it?.let { string1 ->
                doSomething()
                currentState.postValue(String1Updated)
            }
        }
        currentState.addSource(liveData2) {
            it?.let { string1 ->
                doSomethingElse()
                currentState.postValue(String2Updated)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mocking an observer and the repository methods doesn't seem to help. `doSomething()` is never called, and currentState is not updated to String1Updated.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MyViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock lateinit var mockRepository: Repository

    @Mock lateinit var mockLiveData1: MutableLiveData<String>

    @Mock lateinit var mockLiveData2: MutableLiveData<String>

    @Mock lateinit var mockStateObserver: Observer<MyState>

    lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        whenever(mockRepository.getLiveData1()).thenReturn(mockLiveData1)
        whenever(mockRepository.getLiveData2()).thenReturn(mockLiveData2)

        myViewModel = myViewModel(mockRepository)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Does something when live data 1 is updated`() {
        myViewModel.state.observeForever(mockStateObserver)
        mockLiveData1.postValue("hello world")

        verify(mockStateObserver).onChanged(String1Updated)
    }
}
```

Even placing observers directly on `mockLiveData1` and `mockLiveData2` in addition to the observer on the mediator does not cause the sources to be updated in the mediator.

Comment: `mockLiveData1` and `mockLiveData2` should probably not be mocks. Then it would work.

Answer (score 3):

MediatorLiveData needs to have an active Observer for it to trigger its on "onChange" method.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679896/android-mediatorlivedata-observer#45684933).

Comment: Sorry, I left some details out of my post. End of day brain. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 2):

As demonstrated in my post, I was using mock `LiveData` as sources to the mediator data. These should just be `LiveData` implementations.

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    liveData1 = MutableLiveData()
    whenever(mockRepository.getLiveData1()).thenReturn(liveData1)
    liveData1.postValue("initial value")
    myViewModel.state.observeForever(mockStateObserver)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mockLiveData1` and `mockLiveData2` should probably not be mocks.

Then it would work.

(You can also try `@Spy`, I always forget what that does though. But I think you should just instantiate them as regular MutableLiveData instead of `@Mock`.)