# MVVM - MediatorLiveData onChanged not being called

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I'm not sure where I'm implementing MediatorLiveData incorrectly.

I have a Repository class that exposes a mutable live data object:

```
private MutableLiveData<List<UserTransaction>> mTransactionsLiveData
        = new MutableLiveData<>();

public MutableLiveData<List<UserTransaction>> getTransactionsLiveData() {
    return mTransactionsLiveData;
}
```

I have passed reference of this `MutableLiveData` to my `ViewModel` class with a getter:

```
public class UserTransactionsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private LiveData<List<UserTransaction>> mTransactionsLiveData;
    private SharedRepo                      mRepo;

    public UserTransactionsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        mRepo = new SharedRepo(application);
        mTransactionsLiveData = mRepo.getTransactionsLiveData();
    }

    public LiveData<List<UserTransaction>> getTransactionsLiveData() {
        return mTransactionsLiveData;
    }

    public void getUserTransactions(int userId) {
        mRepo.getUserTransactions(userId);
    }


}
```

And in my Fragment class, I am observing it:

```
mViewModel.getTransactionsLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<UserTransaction>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<UserTransaction> list) {

                //Observing it here

                loadDataIntoRecycler(list);
            }
        });
```

Where I am confused:

I am now trying to add a `MediatorLiveData` to format the Data that the `ViewModel` receives from the `Repository` class.

So I first added a new `new MediatorLiveData<>()` in the `ViewModel`

```
private MediatorLiveData<List<UserTransaction>> mediatorLiveData
        = new MediatorLiveData<>();
```

and attached the `.addSource`

```
private MediatorLiveData<List<UserTransaction>> mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();

public UserTransactionsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        mRepo = new SharedRepo(application);
        mTransactionsLiveData = mRepo.getTransactionsLiveData();
        
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(mTransactionsLiveData, new Observer<List<UserTransaction>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<UserTransaction> userTransactions) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: Formatting data...");

                 for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                    list.get(i).setTime("Changing time");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am confused, do I make the observer in the Fragment listen to the `MediatorLiveData`, instead of the `LiveData`? Because the `.onChanged` method on `mediatorLiveData` is never called.

Comment: You listen to only `MediatorLiveData` in Fragment . You do not need `mTransactionsLiveData` just use `mediatorLiveData.addSource(mRepo.getTransactionsLiveData(),.... )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `.onChanged` method on the `mediatorLiveData` is never called [because it's not observed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45684933/3501958).
2. And, if you have already tried to observe the `mediatorLiveData` from the Fragment and `.onChanged` method is still not called, it means the observee is never changed. *Never changed* means never [being `setValue` or `postValue`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#update_livedata_objects).

Like this:

```
mediatorLiveData.addSource(mTransactionsLiveData,
        new Observer<List<UserTransaction>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<UserTransaction> userTransactions) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: Formatting data...");

                for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                    list.get(i).setTime("Changing time");
                }

                mediatorLiveData.setValue(list);
            }
        });
```

Or, using `Transformations.map` (and Java 8 lambda) may be cleaner (while observe `userTransactions` from the Fragment):

```
public LiveData<List<UserTransaction>> userTransactions;

userTransactions = Transformations.map(mTransactionsLiveData, list -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: Formatting data...");

            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                list.get(i).setTime("Changing time");
            }
            return list;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

MediatorLiveData only observes its sources while it's active (has an active observer) so yes, you should observe it in your Fragment. When there are no active observers, onChanged will not be called.

Comment: ive done that but it's not updating the value in my fragment ```mediatorLiveData.addSource(mRepo.getTransactionsLiveData(), new Observer<List<UserTransaction>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<UserTransaction> list) {
                formatTransactionTime(list);
                
            }
        });```