# Using livedata coroutine doesn't gets executed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I am using the liveData coroutine as follows. My function takes 3 params - accessing database, make a API call and return the API result

```
fun <T, A> performGetOperation(
databaseQuery: () -> LiveData<T>,
networkCall: suspend () -> Resource<A>,
saveCallResult: suspend (A) -> Unit
): LiveData<Resource<T>> =
liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    emit(Resource.loading())
    val source = databaseQuery.invoke().map { Resource.success(it) }
    emitSource(source)

    val responseStatus = networkCall.invoke()
    if (responseStatus.status == SUCCESS) {
        saveCallResult(responseStatus.data!!)
    } else if (responseStatus.status == ERROR) {
        emit(Resource.error(responseStatus.message!!))
        emitSource(source)
    }
}
```

I am calling the function as

```
fun getImages(term: String) = performGetOperation(
    databaseQuery = {
        localDataSource.getAllImages(term) },
    networkCall = {
        remoteDataSource.getImages(term) },
    saveCallResult = {
        val searchedImages = mutableListOf<Images>()
        it.query.pages.values.filter {
            it.thumbnail != null
        }.map {
            searchedImages.add(Images(it.pageid, it.thumbnail!!.source, term))
        }
        localDataSource.insertAll(searchedImages)
    }
)
```

This is my viewmodel class

```
class ImagesViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val repository: WikiImageRepository
 ) : ViewModel() {

var images: LiveData<Resource<List<Images>>> = MutableLiveData()

fun fetchImages(search: String) {
    images = repository.getImages(search)
}
}
```

From my fragment I am observing the variable

```
viewModel.images?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        when (it.status) {
            Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                println(it)
            }
            Resource.Status.ERROR ->
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            Resource.Status.LOADING ->
                println("loading")

        }
    })
```

I have to fetch new data on click of button `viewModel.fetchImages(binding.searchEt.text.toString())`

Function doesn't gets executed. Is there something I have missed out?

Comment: I'm trying to move this file to the data layer but it's impossible, because it's pure java, and LiveData can't be imported. Any solution?

Comment: @Patrick which file? Why can't live data be imported?

Comment: performGetOperation function. I have a module Data, which is a java-library, and I cannot not import this function to this layer for the operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `liveData {}` extension function returns an instance of `MediatorLiveData`

```
liveData { .. emit(T) } // is a MediatorLiveData which needs a observer to execute
```

> Why is the `MediatorLiveData` addSource block not executed ?

We need to always *observe* a `MediatorLiveData` using a liveData observer else the source block is never executed

So to make the liveData block execute just observe the liveData,

```
performGetOperation(
    databaseQuery = {
        localDataSource.getAllImages(term) },
    networkCall = {
        remoteDataSource.getImages(term) },
    saveCallResult = {
        localDataSource.insertAll(it)
    }
).observe(lifecyleOwner) { // observing the MediatorLiveData is necessary
}
```

In your case every time you call

```
images = repository.getImages(search)
```

a **new instance** of mediator liveData is created which does not have any observer. The old instance which is observed is ovewritten. You need to observe the new instance of `getImages(...)` again on button click.

```
images.observe(lifecycleOwner) { // on button click we observe again.
     // your observer code goes here
}
```

See [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679896/android-mediatorlivedata-observer)

Comment: I am observing it in my fragment and I have to fetch new data on button click. Still the function doesn't gets executed, I have updated the question. Can you please take a look.

Comment: but u are never observing `perforGetOperation(...)` which needs an observer. We need to observe `perforGetOperation(...)` atleast with a blank observer to make it execute as i have shown in the answer @WISHY

Comment: I am observing that from getImages fun

Comment: on button click u need to observe again , its a separate instance now @WISHY it creates a new instance every time